# How to improve poor performance of EF Core SQL query that sorts on a child collection

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, query-optimization, ef-core-3.1

My issue is with the queries that EF Core generates for fetching ordered items from a child collection of a parent.

I have a parent class which has a collection of child objects. I'm using Entity Framework Core 5.0.5 (code first) against a SQL Server database. I've tried to boil down the scenario, so let's call it an Owner with a collection of Pets.
I often want a list of owners with their oldest pet, so I'll do something like

```
Context.Owners
.Select(owner =>
    new {
       Owner = owner,
       OldPet = owner.Pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Age).LastOrDefault()   
    })
.Where(owner.Id == 1);
```

This worked fine before (on ef6) and works functionally now. However, the issue I have is that now EF Core translates these sub collection queries into something apparently cleverer, something like

```
 SELECT *
  FROM [Owners] AS [c]
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT *
      FROM (
          SELECT [c0].[Id] ... , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [c0].[OwnerId] ORDER BY [c0].[Age] DESC) AS [row]
          FROM [Pets] AS [c0]
      ) AS [t]
      WHERE [t].[row] <= 1
  ) AS [t0] ON [c].[Id] = [t0].[OwnerId]
```

The problem I'm having is that it seems to perform terribly. Looking at the execution plan it's doing a clustered index seek on the pets table, then sorting them. The 'number of rows read' is massive and the 'sorting' takes tens or hundreds of milliseconds.

The way EF6 does the same functionality seemed way more performant in this sort of scenario.

Is there a way to change the behaviour so I can choose? Or a way to rewrite this type of query such that I don't have this problem? I've tried many variations of using GroupBy etc and still have the same result.

Comment: Can you post EF6 query also? For me EF Core did the job correctly.

Comment: I can do, I'll have to recreate it again. Though basically EF6 would do a 'SELECT TOP (1) ..' where EFCore now does this row_number and partition instead.

Comment: `row_number` is correct approach for this query. So trying to understand why EF6 is better. Then we can try to force EF Core to do similar query.

Comment: Would a `OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1` query perform better in your scenario? In other words: what query do you *want* it to generate? We may be able to force EF to generate that. Note that `row_number` generally performs better if most of the inner results are being read, and `top 1` performs better when few are being read. Either way, you need an index `(OwnerId, Age)` potentially also `include` columns

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing `FirstOrDefault` in projection, EF Core has to create such join, which uses Window Function `ROW_NUMBER`. To get desired SQL it is better to rewrite your query to be more predictable for LINQ translator:

```cs
var query =
    from owner in Context.Owners
    from pet in owner.Pets
    where owner.Id == 1
    orderby pet.Age descending
    select new 
    {
        Owner = owner,
        OldPet = pet
    }

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks Svyatoslav, That does create a nice join, but I don't think I can that be made to work if I want multiple owners with each of the pets? I'd end up doing a GroupBy and have the same problem.. Sorry I should have specified that in my question I was trying to over-simplify my example. Just trying some variations now..

Comment: It means that you've missed important part, GroupBy has a serious limitations.